# how to check case insensitivity of properties in Json object and Json Arrays

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I get a json string in a function that string could be json object or List of json objects i.e `[{"user": "123", "password": "abc", "class":"A"}]`.
I want to check if this Json string contains a Property user and password then update their value.
So, I get the string and convert it into `JToken` by using

```
 var jToken = JToken.Parse(result);
 if (jToken is JArray)
   convert into JArray
 else 
   convert into JObject
```

After that I have to check that above keys exist in JArray or JObject.

**Note I want to check the case insensitivity of keys too.**
Can someone help how to check case insensitivity of keys in Json Array and object and modify  their values .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform case-insensitive property lookups via `JObject.Property()`.

```
var json = "[{ 'user':'123','password':'abc','class':'A' }]";
var token = JToken.Parse(json);

foreach (JObject user in token as JArray)
{
    var userProp = user.Property("USER", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (userProp != null)
    {
        userProp.Value = "updated username";
    }

    var passwordProp = user.Property("PaSsWoRd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (passwordProp != null)
    {
        passwordProp.Value = "updated password";
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(token.ToString());
```

This results in the following json:

```
[
  {
    "user": "updated username",
    "password": "updated password",
    "class": "A"
  }
]
```